# Html-servlet checkbox stack

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have this stack, and i am trying to find my mistake but i can't.

When i print the validcheck box the value is null no matter if I check it or if not .

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input   type="checkbox" name="checkboxconfirm" > 
<p style="color:Blue;">I agree to the terms and 
conditions</p</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
boolean validcheckbox = request.getParameter("checkboxconfirm");
out.println("<b>checkbox: </b>" + validcheckbox + "<br>");
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to read the value of the checkbox from the request, instead of from the actual checkbox element

Comment: At last it runned properly when i ran it in incognito window. Maybe it was a problem with the cookies. I have no idea

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.